# How to select child elements under id in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Sample code:

```
<div id='container'>
  <h1>heading 1</h1>
  <h2>heading 2</h2>
  <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I would like a jQuery equivalent of this CSS selector to select the `h1` element under the `div`:

```
#container h1 {}
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can simply implement the *exact same selector*:

```
$('#container h1')
```

Which selects every `h1` element found within the `#container` element, or:

```
$('#container > h1')
```

Which selects only those `h1` elements that have the `#container` element as their parent (*not* grandparent, or other form of ancestor).

Or, if you prefer:

```
$('#container').find('h1')
```

You could also restrict it to a particular `h1` element:

```
$('#container h1:first')
```

Which selects only the *first* `h1` element within the `#container` element.

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).