# Selecting child element under <section>

Tags: javascript, html

I've encountered this problem while trying to append a list item to a class under a parent section which have an id name. So, assume that I have 2 sections with different ids. And I'd like to append message to the first section. Here is the HTML code.

```
  <section id="to1" class="privateMsg">
    <p class="toWho">To 1<a href="#" class="close">x</a></p>
    <ul class="messages">  <!-- I want to grab this element -->
      <li>...</li>         <!-- so that I could append message here -->
    </ul>
    <form class="sendPMsg" action="/" method="post">
      <input placeholder="Your message..." type="text">
      <button name="send" type="button" class="sendPrivateBtn">Send</button>
    </form>
  </section>

  <section id="to2" class="privateMsg">
    <p class="toWho">To 2<a href="#" class="close">x</a></p>
    <ul class="messages">  <!-- but not this one -->
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    <form class="sendPMsg" action="/" method="post">
      <input placeholder="Your message..." type="text">
      <button name="send" type="button" class="sendPrivateBtn">Send</button>
    </form>
  </section>
```

How can I do this with javaScript? I have tried:

```
  var idCheck = 'to'+frmUser;
  var privateChatExist = document.getElementById(idCheck);
  if ( privateChatExist != null) {
    // this is where I have problem
    $(".messages").append('<li><a class="user ' + frmUser + '" href="#">' + frmUser + '</a>: ' + msgContent + '</li></ul>');
  }
  else {
    // add new section
  }
```

but it appended to both sections, since they both have messages class. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your first selector from `$(".messages")` to `$("#" + idCheck + " .messages")`  which would come out to be something like `$("#to1 .messages")` for the first id, `$("#to2 .messages")` for the second, and so forth

Answer (score 0):

You need your `.message` selector to be more specific to which section you want it to reflect.

`$("#"+ idCheck + "> .messages")`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `$(".messages")` with `$("#" + idCheck + " > .messages")`. This will give you only elements with the class messages that are children of an element with the id of your idCheck variable. The `>` character is used to perform a search only among immediate children of a specific node or nodes.

There's lots of other ways to limit results from jQuery selectors. See: [How to select child elements under id in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819622/jquery-how-to-select-child-elements-under-id)