# How to get a specific form elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multiple forms in a page and i would like to get the elements of a specific form. For example:

```
<form class="form" id="1">
  <input type="text" name="message" value="message">
  <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
<form class="form" id="2">
  <input type="text" name="message" value="message">
  <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

How to get the value of message of form id=2...... Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery- how to select child elements under id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819622/jquery-how-to-select-child-elements-under-id)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use attribute selectors

```
 $('form[id=2]') // get the form with id = 2
.find('input[name=message]') // locate the input element with attribute name = message
.attr("value"); //  get the attribute = value
```

Comment: Instead of `.attr("value")` you could alternatively call `.val()` which is more handy (to me), but it is just my personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't use raw numbers for ids, let's rename those to form_1 and form_2, then your jquery selector would be:

```
$("#form_2 [name='message']").val();
```

Comment: this would get select the element with id #form_2 which doesn't exist.

Comment: I mentioned renaming the forms in my post

Answer (score 0):

Simply query the `input` from the `id` of the form you'd like

```js
console.log($('#2 input').val());

//more specific
console.log($('#2 input[name="message"]').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" id="1">
  <input type="text" name="message" value="message">
  <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
<form class="form" id="2">
  <input type="text" name="message" value="message">
  <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery, or you can use basic JavaScript to return the message value. With basic JS, you would have to give your form a name, but then could return the message value.

Code:

```
function getValue() {
    var message = document.forms["form_name"]["message"].value;
}
```

You would then have to return the function when the form is submitted

```
<form class="form" name="form_name" onsubmit="return getValue()">
```