# Jquery Children() Filteration

Tags: jquery

please take a look at this

```js
$(() => {
  const keys = $("#numbers").children();
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    console.log($(keys[i]));
    if (keys.is("br")) {
      console.log("Br FOUND");
    }
  }
});
```

AND

```html
<section class="keyboard">
    <input type = "text" class="input">
    <br>
    <div id="numbers">
        <button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button><br><button>4</button><button>5</button><button>6</button><br><button>7</button><button>8</button><button>9</button><br><button>0</button><button>.</button>
    </div>
    <button id = "calc">calculate</button><br>
    <button id = "clear">clear</button>
</section>
```

this is a jquery script i wrote , so i have a calculator app so i separated the numbers into groups each group holds  three numbers with `<br>` at the end
so i'm using children() build-in method in jquery to get all the div's children so there're 3 `<br>` tags in it so i wonder how can i remove them from the list .... actually is the keys constant is list or jquery object? and how can i deal with it in my case?

i actually have solved this problem using `.find()` method in jquery but i want to know how to deal with such theis things using `.children()` method

Comment: jQuery's `.children()` takes an optional selector as an argument, see: https://api.jquery.com/children/. So you _could_ use: `$('#numbers').children('button')`

Comment: Or just include the tag you want in the selector... `$('#numbers > button')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select child elements under id in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819622/how-to-select-child-elements-under-id-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a selector to the `.children()` method to tell it which children to return to you:

```
$("#numbers").children("button")
```

However, since the jQuery method takes CSS selectors, you might as well just write it directly in there and skip using `.children()` entirely:

```
$("#numbers > button")
```

Here's a demo showing how many items each selector returns

```js
$(() => {
  console.log('jQuery all children count', $("#numbers").children().length)
  console.log('jQuery button children count', $("#numbers").children("button").length)
  console.log('jQuery simpler selector count', $("#numbers > button").length)
});jQuery
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="keyboard">
    <input type = "text" class="input">
    <br>
    <div id="numbers">
        <button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button><br><button>4</button><button>5</button><button>6</button><br><button>7</button><button>8</button><button>9</button><br><button>0</button><button>.</button>
    </div>
    <button id = "calc">calculate</button><br>
    <button id = "clear">clear</button>
</section>
```